# Create timebased trigger in side a for loop (apps script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In an apps script project, i have to run a task that will take about 2 hours to complete,
so i decided to break it in parts and run each via timebased trigger.
In the below snippet:
the function longAction represent the function that needs to be run multiple times and this function will accept arguments a and b.

the lowerUpper() function returns a list of ranges[0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, 20-20], these represent row numbers in a googlesheet.

I tried creating copies of the longAction function using the bind method.
Which in turn i want to use in the ScriptApp timebased c while creating trigger.

Result: The triggers are created (ok).
Problem: I have the following error

Script function not found: function () { [native code] }

How can i correct the error? Or any other way of dealing with the problem.

I expected to create timebased triggers where each trigger runs the same function but with a different set of argument.

I have the following error:
Script function not found: function () { [native code] }

```
let longAction = function (a,b){
    for(let i =a ; i<= b ; i++){
        Logger.log(i) // for testing purpose
    }
 }

function test(){
    let rng = lowerUpper(20,4) // [0-4, 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, 20-20]

    for (j = 0; j < rng.length ; j++){
        let low = rng[j].split('-')[0]
        let upper = rng[j].split('-')[1]
 
    // create copies of longAction function to    use later in the trigger
        let action1 = longAction.bind(null,low,upper) 

       ScriptApp.newTrigger(action1)
       .timeBased()
       .after(1 * 60 * 1000)
       .create()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass arguments to triggered function.  All of the trigger pass information via an event object to their handler function. Which always get's loaded in the first parameter.  You can use propertiesService or even cacheService to get the needed information for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
function longAction(a,b){
    for(let i =a ; i<= b ; i++){
        Logger.log(i) // for testing purpose
    }
 }
```

Now you will have the problem that the event object will be passed into a and there is no workaround for that.

So give the cacheService or the propertyService a try.

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank your for the suggestion. I have never used the cacheService or the propertyService, do you happen to have a link or code snippet which can be useful for my case?

Comment: I think this close to what you require [Using PropertiesService](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74101821/7215091)